# React-router example don't work

Tags: javascript, react-router-v4

I try to run example from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-config/README.md#renderroutesroutes

Server side code:

```
 router.get('/*', function(ctx, next) {
   const context = {};
   const initialState = {};
   const appStore = createAppStore(null, initialState);

   const appString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={appStore} key="provider">
        <StaticRouter location={ctx.url} context={context}>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
   );
  ...
```

(routes - just copypast from example page)
  after request on some route i get always the Home page

if I use my own routes

```
const routes =
[
  { path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home
  },
  { path: '/about',
    component: About
  }
]
```

on both of routes I also get the Home page, click Link don't work and don't log any error

my repo: https://github.com/kirsanv43/react-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/src/server.js

Comment: example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but when I copy renderRoutes function from  [react-router-config](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-config/modules/renderRoutes.js) to my project and use it, all work completely great.